# Qt with QWebEngine install with yum

Tags: qt, redhat, yum

Using Ubuntu 14.04 I had a dilemma that the QWebEngine was not available with the "apt-get" Qt install.

I figured out that I need to add the "ethereum" software repository:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

Once I did this I was able to see the following when I did a apt-cache search of "webengine":

```
qtwebengine5-dev
libqt5webengine5
```

This leads me back to my original question.

I'm trying to install Qt with QWebEngine on Red Hat 7 and CentOS 7 which do not have "apt-get"...correct me if I'm wrong. I know that they do use "yum" for software installs.

What is the "yum" equivalent of "apt-get" when installing Qt with QWebEngine on RedHat/CentOS?

Comment: what is the output yum search QWebEngine or dnf search QWebEngine? try with `sudo yum install qt5-qtwebengine qt5-qtwebengine-devel` or `sudo dnf install qt5-qtwebengine qt5-qtwebengine-devel`

Comment: I'll give that a try...I'll let you know they yum output as soon as I try it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @eyllanesc I see that the names of the qt modules differ between Ubuntu and RedHat. The reason this concerns me is because I was trying to add dependencies to an rpmbuild spec file but how do I do it across 2 different platforms if the components have different names because they use different repositories? Do I need to have 2 different spec files?

Comment: Each distro has a different group of developers, and each group establishes a name for it the difference. On the other hand I have not worked with rpmbuild but I suppose that 1) it will have a configuration section that indicates the distro or version or 2) it allows to pass the .so so that they do not depend on the OS or 3) you must generate an rpm for each distro.